# How can I pass a value from v-select to method - it always stays the same as the default

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

I have a function I want to pass a value to in my Vue app using v-select.
v-select is populated from a data array 'chapters'.
I then want to use the selected id to pass to a function.

I have an empty data variable 'chapterIdFilter' in my data return which is set to a value of 1 - this pre-filters my vuetify data table

How can I pass the value of the id - chapterIdFilter - from my v-select dropdown to a function in my methods so I can filter the table with it?
The chapterIdFilter is always '1'

```
    <v-select
          :model="chapterIdFilter"
          :items="chapters"
          item-text="locale.en.title"
          item-value="id"
          label="Filter by Chapter"
          @change="currentDataItems(chapterIdFilter)"
        />
```

Method:

```
currentDataItems (chapterIdFilter) {
    console.log(chapterIdFilter)
    return this.portals.filter(val => val.chapterId === parseInt(chapterIdFilter)) // this.portals.filter(val => val.chapterId === '1')
  }
```

UPDATE:

So the code below works as desired but I am not sure it should or know why

```
    currentDataItems (chapterIdFilter) {
  
    console.log(chapterIdFilter)
    this.chapterIdFilter = chapterIdFilter
    return this.portals.filter(val => val.chapterId === parseInt(this.chapterIdFilter)) 
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind `v-model` directive to the data property and use it with  `this` in your method :

```
    <v-select
          v-model="chapterIdFilter"
          :items="chapters"
          item-text="locale.en.title"
          item-value="id"
           return-object
          label="Filter by Chapter"
          @change="currentDataItems"
        />
```

method:

```
currentDataItems () {
    console.log(this.chapterIdFilter)
    return this.portals.filter(val => val.chapterId === parseInt(this.chapterIdFilter))
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Boussadjra - Oddly that still returns the default value. If return chapterIdFilter in current items argument then i get the id value of the selected option. Changing  @change="currentDataItems" seems to pass it because it is binded?
I'll update with the code i got working but I am puzzled why it works

Comment: try to add `return-object` prop like `<v-select return-object ...`